# Apply a condition to an index based on the values in a list

Tags: pandas

I have a df:

```
              A   B   C

    'F'      2    4   ss1
    'G'      3    4   ss1
```

Then I have a list1:

```
['ss1','ss4']
```

I would like that if any element of the list1 exists in column C of the df, then apply a space to the beginning of the index name to obtain this output:

```
              A   B   C

    ' F'      2    4   ss1
    ' G'      3    4   ss1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) or [`Index.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.where.html) and condition with [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html):

```
df.index = np.where(df['C'].isin(list1), ' ' + df.index, df.index)
```

Or:

```
df.index = df.index.where(~df['C'].isin(list1), ' ' + df.index)
```